# IIS error with every launch of an ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a problem with using the new ASP.NET Core MVC. I make an empty project or use a web application template. Every time I save changes to any file in Visual Studio 2015 file browser or every time I launch the app with or without debugging, an IIS error pops up:

> "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application: The directory
>   name C:\Users\COMPUTERNAME=ZENBOOK is invalid".

What could this path be? Never changed anything in any settings that could trigger such a thing.

The rest of the error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: The directory name C:\Users\vouCOMPUTERNAME=ZENBOOK\ is invalid.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path(String value)
   at Microsoft.IisExpress.SysTray.TrayAppHiddenForm.TrayAppHiddenForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The site is rendered just fine with any refresh. But this error keeps appearing - on two different machines. It never happens with an MVC 4 project, though... My friend, however, does not have any similar problems with ASP.NET Core MVC.

I feel it may have to do with Environment variables, but I checked, they seem to be fine. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Zenbook" username make sense to you? Is that you?

Also, your stack trace describes a problem when executing Windows Forms code. Is there any reason for you to be using any of that?
Check your design as that does not make sense, at least to a person not aware of what your application does.

Comment: "Zenbook" is just the name of the machine, that's me, yes.

It's just any default Web Application template. So, it's a web app project, don't really know how WinForms is involved...

Comment: Well its a bit hard from me to say without actually seeing it but I'd suggest that you try to find that code. Start with looking at dlls or installed nugent packages.

Comment: ************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
...

Comment: that's what IIS shows, if I try to see all its processes...how does one even trace this code?